# finding connected Wifi network

Tags: qt, wifi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

How do I retrieve the name of the WiFi that the system is connected to. So far I'm querying with the following but it is returning interface names instead of Wifi names:

```
    QNetworkConfigurationManager nwkMgr;
    QList<QNetworkConfiguration> nwkCnfList = nwkMgr.allConfigurations();
    for(const QNetworkConfiguration &ncnf : nwkCnfList)
    {
        qDebug() << ncnf.name() << ncnf.bearerType();
        if (ncnf.bearerType() == QNetworkConfiguration::BearerWLAN)
        {
           // would like to detect WiFi here
           qDebug() << "WiFi:" << ncnf.name();
        }
    }
```

This lists the interfaces:

```
"Wired connection 1" 1
"ens33" 1
```

How can I get the NAME of the Wifi?

Comment: In Qt 5.13.1 returns the names of the Wi-Fi to which the device is connected. Maybe it's a bug from the version of Qt you use.

Comment: I’m using QtWebkit...not offered in 5.13

Comment: QtWebkit is a submodule that provides a WebView API, it has nothing to do with QtNetwork which is the sub module you use. In conclusion, QtWebkit has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Is there any other way to obtain the WiFi that the system is connected to programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use system variables ? If so do this:

```
export WNAME=$(iw dev | grep ssid | awk '{print $2}')
```

It will export it to a variable WNAME and you can use it inside scripts untill you logout or shutdown the system.